# Order Categories by Character Count

Tags: categories, loop, taxonomy, array

I'm developing a medical directory website in Wordpress, and in the Grid/List pages for the site, each of the listing cards contains a list of specialties (using the category taxonomy within the dDoctors/Directorist theme & plugin). Currently, these specialties are displaying in each of the grid cards in alphabetical order in a Flexbox wrap. Because of the limited space, sometimes there might be some wasted white space in the container. Case in point the following grid card which by default appears as so:

```
<ul>
    <li>Emergency</li>
    <li>Hospice Home Care</li>
    <li>ICU (NICU)</li>
    <li>Med/Surg</li>
    <li>OB</li>
    <li>Oncology</li>
</ul>
```

Which looks like this on the page:

[image]

I used Developer Tools to rearrange the items so that they're listed in order of least to most character count per category, showing like this in code:

```
<ul>
    <li>OB</li>
    <li>Med/Surg</li>
    <li>Oncology</li>
    <li>ICU (NICU)</li>
    <li>Emergency</li><li>Hospice Home Care</li>
</ul>
```

and the code generated on the page as so (with one less line, SCORE!):

[image]

So clearly, it appears if I want to optimize the display of these items, they should be arranged in character count order, but to my knowledge, neither Wordpress nor my plugin/theme support this arrangement by default.

The PHP loop that generates this list is located inside the plugins/directorist/templates/archive/fields/category.php file, and looks like this:

```
<ul>
   <?php foreach ( $listings->loop['cats'] as $cat ) {

        $output = '<li>' . $cat->name . '</li>';
        
        echo $output;    
        
       };
   ?>
</ul>
```

How can I get this list to be sorted by character count? I would guess I would need to declare a variable for the character count, and then generate a new foreach that sorts it by that. Do I have that correctly, and how would I go about doing that?

Comment: if you have a list of categories and know how to get their names and loop over them, then can't you use general PHP to sort them by length? I'm not sure how WordPress knowledge specifically is necessary here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably more a question about PHP rather than WordPress, and as such may be closed as off-topic for this site.

That said, you can [`usort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort an array using a custom comparison function:

```php
usort(
  $listings->loop['cats'],
  function( $a, $b ){
    return strlen( $a->name ) - strlen( $b->name );
  }
);
```

After the call above, the `$listings->loop['cats']` array will be ordered from smallest category name to largest.

Sorting from shortest to longest will pack all of the smallest items together nicely - but it also concentrates the largest items, which may ultimately take up an entire line a piece if not paired with a short item. A more space-efficient approach is likely one which would mix long and short items, but it might not feasible if you don't have a rough measure of the width constraint beforehand.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and apologies for posting in the wrong StackExchange site. I did try that code, putting it either before or after my foreach, but unfortunately neither changed the order of the items. Perhaps I should reach out in the PHP StackExchange site for further guidance...

Comment: Ahh - I missed that `$listings->loop['cats']` was an array of term objects, I was thinking it was just an array of strings. I've corrected the comparison function. In any scenario, the PHP Stack site would be [so] :)

Comment: That did work. I put it before my foreach. I'll keep in mind in the future to post to Stack Overflow. Thanks for your assistance!